# How to parse ID through URL with Inner Join

Tags: php, mysql

I have a code that work well if I specify in my query the ID I want. However, when trying to parse it through URL it doesn't work.

```
if(!$rs = mysql_query("SELECT id_player, fight, sh, pl, st, ch, ma, hi, sk, en, pe, fa, le, str, team, contract_lenght, main_position, alternate_position, salary, player_name, TRUNCATE(((sh + pl + st)/3),0) AS OFF, TRUNCATE(((ch + ma + hi)/3),0) as DEF, TRUNCATE(((sh + pl + st + ch + ma + hi + sk + en + pe + fa + le + str + pot + con + greed)/15),0) as OV, main_position.id, main_position.type_main_position, alternate_position.id, alternate_position.type_alternate_position, nom_equipe_nhl.team_id, nom_equipe_nhl.team_name, nom_equipe_nhl.team_abr FROM players_nhl INNER JOIN nom_equipe_nhl ON nom_equipe_nhl.team_id = players_nhl.team INNER JOIN main_position ON players_nhl.main_position = main_position.id INNER JOIN alternate_position ON players_nhl.alternate_position = alternate_position.id WHERE id_player='$id_player'")) {
```

I also got this at the top of my page..

```
<?php
$id_player = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id_player']);
?>
```

If I replace $id_player with a number, it works, but if I parse through my url with ?id_player=25  .. I always got a not found result.

I tried many things but can't seem to make it work. However, If i replace all the Inner join and everything after "as OV" and From Players... it works. Ie;

```
if(!$rs = mysql_query("SELECT id_player, fight, sh, pl, st, ch, ma, hi, sk, en, pe, fa, le, str, team, contract_lenght, main_position, alternate_position, salary, player_name, TRUNCATE(((sh + pl + st)/3),0) AS OFF, TRUNCATE(((ch + ma + hi)/3),0) as DEF, TRUNCATE(((sh + pl + st + ch + ma + hi + sk + en + pe + fa + le + str + pot + con + greed)/15),0) as OV FROM players_nhl WHERE id_player='$id_player'")) {
```

I'd really need to have the id parse through URL with the inner join.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure about `mysql_*` functions? They have been removed from PHP. You should definitely switch to mysqli or PDO.

Comment: All my code is old, in the future I would probably siwtch to mysqli or pdo, but I'd really want to have this work as is right now if possible.

Comment: If it stops at 25 are you sure you have an ID=25?

Comment: Also `contract_lenght` seems like a typo.

Comment: tadman, yes, I got over 3000 rows and it work if I put 25 directly in my query. As for the contract_lenght, I agree it could look like a typo but this mistake was made by the person who created the table and mispelled it ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_real_escape_string()
```

This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0
you should use mysqli or pdo.

That's the right syntax:

```
$id_player = mysqli_real_escape_string($your_connection_object, $_GET['id_player']);
```

or in OOP notation:

```
$your_connection_object->real_escape_string();
```

The same as described is for mysql_query()...

```
mysql_query("SELECT id_player,...
```

becomes

```
mysqli_query($your_connection_object, $your_query);
```

or in OOP:

```
$your_connection_object->query($your_query);
```

Comment: The OOP form is the only one really worth teaching. It's much less verbose and it makes it nearly impossible to use `mysql_query` by accident, such as forgetting an `i` in the function call.